# Why won't text on a label show up on an actual device but will in the simulator? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, simulator

*Running :*
 - Latest version of Xcode
 - Catalina 10.15.2
 - Base model MacBook Pro 13 inch

I'm having an issue where when I have text in a label show up on the simulator but when I try running it on my iPad, it is just blank. The text is currently being shown on the simulator because that is what I have just typed in on the label on the main.storyboard.

I have tried setting the label text manually by doing `myLabel.text = "myText"` but that didn't work either. Each device is up to date in terms of the software and I have chosen iOS 13/iPad OS for what software the simulator should run on also. I'm thinking it is just some weird iOS 13 bug because I can't find a fix for it.

**On iPad**
[image: ipadImage]

**on Simulator**
[image: simulatorImage]

Comment: where is image?

Comment: (Simulator) https://imgur.com/hDIUuoC

(iPad) https://imgur.com/BxJbsco

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check if `Dark mode` is `enabled` or not on the actual device, if it is then try changing the color of the text to something else like: `BlackColor` because if the text color is `labelColor` then on devices with dark mode enabled it will appear `white`.