# Labels are not visible in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin

I just recently started Xamarin.Forms. I run the following code by deploying it to my own IPhone device. The code is the default code that is added whenever a new page is added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestReal.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem is that the label that is supposed to say "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" doesn't appear. I tried rotating the screen, giving it a bigger padding and margin. Giving it a different background color, foreground color and etc. However a slider or a button is displayed correctly. Just the label is not visible.

Comment: Does it work on simulator ? You could delete the folder bin and obj in the project , then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT clearing the bin folder and rebuilding the app didnt change anything whatsoever. Interesting enough it does work in simulations. However the version of the phone matches with deployment target version.

Comment: Do you have any iOS settings which could affect that label style, like accessibility size, colors, theme? The layout looks good and the fact it works on sim says that the code is correct.

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh No, I don't think I do. How can I check if I do or not? and even though I have some settings that might affect label size how can I fix it in the application.

Comment: Create a new blank project and then test again . If the issue still appear , you could post the issue to github .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT check my answer I have resolved the issue. It was caused by the fact that the automatic color of labels is white in dark mode.

Comment: Which means my assumption was correct. Device theme can affect the way controls are rendered by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue. Since the dark mode was on on my IPhone device the text was looking white. When dark mode is turned off I am able to see the label and it works as expected.

Try this: [Why won't text on a label show up on an actual device but will in the simulator? (Xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525852/why-wont-text-on-a-label-show-up-on-an-actual-device-but-will-in-the-simulator)